# Appium iOS | Can't clear user cache

Tags: ios, appium, webdriver-io, appium-ios, saucelabs

So I have recently stumbled across a "fun" thing for automation and test case runs in general - and that is that **iOS is very persistent with the users cache and won't let you delete the apps cache**.

**The actual issue:**

- first test case runs fine and logs in the user
- the second test case expects the user to be logged out | expects to run on a fresh app - without any left over cache from the previous user <- so because of that it FAILS

**I have tried several solutions:**

- adding capabilities like `noReset` or/and `fullReset`
- stopping the driver (deleting the app and reinstating it again)
- basically everything I could find - I tried

I have managed to fix the issue for **SIMULATOR** but not for the **REAL DEVICE**.

If you are doing any appium webdriver automation for your mobile applications - you should have encountered this issue and had to deal with it somehow - **would really appreciate your opinion on this topic!** (Also I am using SauceLabs for the real devices)

P.s. I don't want to make silly workarounds like loging out the user after each test case - so the next one could start from a fresh app and so on. IMHO this would be a really bad practise | shot-lived workaround.

Edit - code examples.
**Capabilities:**

```
config.capabilities = [
  {
    platformName: 'iOS',
    'appium:platformVersion': getRandomOsVersion(osVersions),
    'appium:deviceName': 'iPhone .*',
    'appium:automationName': 'XCUITest',
    'appium:app': 'storage:filename=app.ipa',
    'appium:autoAcceptAlerts': true,
    'appium:connectHardwareKeyboard': true,
    'appium:shouldTerminateApp': true,
    'appium:newCommandTimeout': 240,
    'sauce:options': {
      build: buildName,
      name: buildName,
      allowTouchIdEnroll: false,
      sauceLabsImageInjectionEnabled: false,
    },
  },
];
```

**Test cases:**

```
describe('Login functionality', () => {

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await driver.reset();
        (await WelcomeScreen.getStartedButton).waitForDisplayed();
    });

    it('Login with user (finished profile)', async () => {
        await WelcomeScreen.getStartedButton.click();
        await LoginScreen.submitLogin(USER_CREDENTIALS.USER_WITH_FINISHED_PROFILE);
        await expect(await FeaturesTourScreen.letsGetYouStarted).toBeDisplayed(); 
    });

    it('Login with user incorrect credentials', async () => {
        await WelcomeScreen.getStartedButton.click();
        await LoginScreen.submitLogin(USER_CREDENTIALS.INCORRECT_CREDENTIALS);
        await expect(await LoginScreen.alertMesage).toBeDisplayed();
    });
    
});
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information about what you did, for examples your capabilities, is your second testcase in the same file, or in a separate, was this locally or on Sauce Labs (you tagged it with Sauce Labs) and so on

Comment: For the capabilities - I have tried adding or removing most of the stuff there is for this issue. My TCs are in the same file and in the same describe block, like this. 
describe('login' { 
it(('first TC'){ // log in with correct credentials});
it(('second TC'){ // try to login with wrong credentials});
});

Locally I use xcodes simulator - so with the simulator everything works fine. 
When I run the code on Sauce Labs - it uses real ios devices and so the issue occurs there.

Comment: Thanks for the info, can you put all requested info in your ticket, so caps, a sample test and so on. I will then try to answer it for you.

Comment: I have updated the question and added the code examples :)

Comment: Last question, what do you mean with this "...without any left over cache from the previous user..", you assume that all data is removed, even the logged in/registered account?

Answer (score 0):

**Real Device background**

Real devices behave differently in comparison to Simulators. When you install an iOS app on a real device it needs to be resigned so it is allowed to install the app. Removing an app "might" remove all data that has been stored on the device / keystore, but data could still be attached to your iCloud account.
There are no Appium commands to remove the data stored in the keystore or in the app itself

**WebdriverIO background**

This is not even 100% specific for WebdriverIO, but when you run 2 tests (`it`) from a single file the end state of the first test will be the starting state of the second test. You can control that with a `beforeEach/afterEach`, but this will have no/less effect on real devices.
WebdriverIO spins up a single driver for every test file. In theory this should lead to a clean simulator / device when the second test-file is starting

**Sauce Labs background**

When you are using Sauce Labs you don't have the option to remove the app between the first and second `it`, because when you remove the app it needs to be resigned and this is not supported. Options like `noReset|fullReset` won't have an effect on iOS real devices.
If you need to have all data cleared then you need to:

- or have a backdoor in your app to do this through Appium
- run the second test case in a new spec file. WebdriverIO spins up a new instance for every test file and in between the app is removed and the device is cleaned

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer! I will be trying to implement the backdoor solution and if that does not work or is too complicated for the devs (requires too much time resource) to do - I will then split the `it` test case to separate files :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you ask the developers of the application to add data cleanup logic in the code itself that runs when a specific `launch argument` is provided when starting the application. Then you can use the Appium capability `processArguments` to provide that argument to the app when starting the test and the app itself will cleanup the data. [Example](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9659) for providing arguments from Appium issues, Appium [XCUITest](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver) driver official docs describing the capability

Comment: This is a good solution, on of the possible backdoors I referred to. But how would this processArgument work for cleaning the session without reinstalling the app?

Comment: I haven't done it myself, I've only worked with such a solution provided by the dev team for me. It not only cleaned the session, but even cleaned webview cookies since it was hybrid app. I suppose the app can access the keychain and clean it, also clean data from `UserDefaults` store. I am really speaking from the perspective of just a consumer of such a solution but it can definitely be achieved

Comment: thank you! I will call our head of mobile department and discuss this possibility :)